# Azure diagnostic show api calls by taken time

Tags: azure, kql, azure-diagnostics

How can I get top x uniqe api calls from azure diagnostics? Currently I use the next snippet:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess" and requestUri_s startswith "/api"
| top 20 by timeTaken_d
| project timeTaken_d, requestUri_s
```

Output:

| Uri | Time |
| --- | --- |
| /api/path_1 | 40,352 |
| /api/path_1 | 38,792 |
| /api/path_2 | 35,792 |

How can I aggregate the data by `Uri` ?

Comment: Exactly what aggregation(s) would you like?

Comment: @Dai I'd like to aggreate it by uri. In the example above I'd like to see two rows: /api/path_1 + 79.144; /api/path_2 + 35.792

Answer (score 1):

###### Option 1

[top-nested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/topnestedoperator) operator

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess" and requestUri_s startswith "/api"
| top-nested 20 of requestUri_s by sum(timeTaken_d)
```

###### Option 2

[summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) & [top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/topoperator) operators

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess" and requestUri_s startswith "/api"
| summarize sum(timeTaken_d) by requestUri_s
| top 20 by sum_timeTaken_d
```